# PrimeFaces dialog isn't displayed properly after ajax call that update=@all

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a single page application written in JSF - PrimeFaces.
There are a couple of dialogs that are displayed correctly at the begining.
But after clicking:

```
<p:menuitem value="Logout" update="@all" action="#{loginBean.logout}"/>
```

the dialogs don't open correctly.

Comment: refreshing the page is recommended when you do a logout, I imagine you're terminating the session... so in my opinion ajax logout may cause problems..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is is possible for you to make an update elements list, for example like:
 update=":a:b,:c,:d:e:f".

Many people complains when try to use "@all".

Comment: You are right, update='@all' seams problematic, I changed to to 'ajax=false'. Thanks!

Comment: 'just' changing ajax to false will have other effects. You should be sure what you are doing to your code! update=@all reloads all dialogs and that will propably cause your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can also use, its like to show dialog force fully

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" ....... />
```

and use `onClick = "PF('statusDialog').show();"`